# Can we get a polynomial time algorithm from a naively exponential one, because of a linear formula that's bounded?

Tags: inequality, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

Let $X_i \subset \Bbb{N}$ be the total choices (naively figured) in some algorithm for succesively presented options $i=1..n$ Then naively there are $\prod_{i=1}^n |X_i|$ possible **combinations** of choices to check.

But what if we know something more, that for each choice vector $(x_i) \in X_1 \times \dots \times X_n$ that we *actually care about*, we have the bound:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i \leq s
$$

where $a_i, s \in \Bbb{N}$ are fixed for a given algorithm input.

> **Question**: Can we *efficiently* design a decision tree with *alot less* combinations than the naive count?  Namely, can we get a polynomial-sized decision tree with respect to $n$, that was constructed in polynomial time?

You can assume each $X_i$ is for the most part a range of whole numbers.

Also you can assume that the upper bound of $X_i$ is precisely $|X_i|$ so for simplicity of analysis, assume that $X_i = \{1, \dots, |X_i|\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $a_i,s$, yes, you're bounded by  $ { {\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i| } \choose s }$.  I'm not sure of your motivation for doing so,  perhaps you would be interested in the theory of kernelization https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2015/lecture-videos/lecture-18-complexity-fixed-parameter-algorithms/

Comment: well if you think of x as choosing from {0,1}^{\sum |X_i| } then for fixed s you have at most  sum |X_i|  choose s which is polynomial degree s (assuming all a_i at least 1)    
or you can use a stars and bars type argument how many  ways are there for n integers to sum to s?  its about (n+s) \choose s  which is poly for fixed s

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something because once you have $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq s$  and $x_i \in \{ 0,1,..,\} $ then there are only  $ { {s+n+1} \choose {n+1} } = { {s+n+1} \choose {s+1}  }  =O(n^s)$  possible options right?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)  
unless I'm misunderstanding something